# Converting DataFrame to dictionary with header as key and column as array with values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
A B C 
1 6 1 
2 5 7 
3 4 9
4 2 2
```

I want a dictionary like this:

```
{A: [1,2,3,4], B:[6,5,4,2], C:[1,7,9,2]}
```

I have tried using the normal `df.to_dict()` and it is no where close. If  I use the transposed dataframe, hence `df.T.to_dict()` it gets close, but I have something like this:

```
{0: {A: 1, B: 6, C:1} , ... , 4:{A: 4, B: 2, C: 2 } }
```

The questions in stack overflow are limited to the dictionary having one value per key, not an array.

It would be very valuable for me to use `to_dict()` and avoid any for loop, since the database I am using is quite big and I want the computational complexity to be as low as possible.

Comment: `df.to_dict(orient='list')` or `df.to_dict('l')`

Comment: Try playing with the `orient=` keyword in `to_dict`

Comment: @piRSquared It worked, you should put it as an official answer.

Comment: By the way, would it be possible to preserve it as a numpy array and not just a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `orient='list'`

```
df.to_dict(orient='list')
```

Or: the method actually just checks the first character

```
df.to_dict('l')
```

If you want to preserve the numpy array

```
{k: v.to_numpy() for k, v in df.items()}
```

Comment: Would the computational cost increase a lot if you preserve it as a numpy array?

Comment: Not really.  That should be pretty snappy.